# How to get current mouse cursor or handle resize event in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, cursor, mouse

I need to handle an event before resizing of an object. I need to know this information during selection event.
My guess was to get the current cursor from mouse and check, if it is in resizing type. I tried to call

```
Mouse.OverrideCursor
```

but it returned null. Can anyone help me to get the current cursor?
My other guess was to check, if the mouse is over the edge of the object. Is it possible to check it somehow? I use

```
ContentControl
```

objects, which are put to

```
Canvas
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found solution by myself. I get the mouseover information from my resize decorator template, which I have declared in my xaml.

```
Control thumb = this.Template.FindName("PART_ResizeDecorator", this) as Control;
bool resizing = thumb.IsMouseOver;
```

This seems to be more elegant than checking for actual cursor, but still it might be interesting to know how to get it. So feel free to reply my question.